# What does a loss list in Keras mean?

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I've just seen

```
# Combined model trains generators to fool discriminators
self.combined = Model(inputs=[img_A, img_B],
                      outputs=[ valid_A, valid_B,
                                reconstr_A, reconstr_B,
                                img_A_id, img_B_id ])
self.combined.compile(loss=['mse', 'mse',
                            'mae', 'mae',
                            'mae', 'mae'],
                    loss_weights=[  1, 1,
                                    self.lambda_cycle, self.lambda_cycle,
                                    self.lambda_id, self.lambda_id ],
                    optimizer=optimizer)
```

in [CycleGan](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN/blob/master/cyclegan/cyclegan.py) - what does the list of losses mean / do? Before, I only worked with exactly one loss function per model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This model has multiple inputs (two) and multiple outputs (six), so you need to specify one loss function for each output. That's why there is a list of losses.

Additionally a model can only be trained with a single loss function, and for a multi-output model, this is accomplished by creating a virtual loss that is a weighted combination of all per-output losses, and this is what the `loss_weights` parameter is for.

Answer (score 1):

It is also worth noting that you need to provide a list of loss functions for a multi-output model only if the loss functions used are NOT all the same. For example, if all the output layers use the Mean Squared Error loss, then you only need to provide `loss='mse'`.